# How to use awk's output on bash command line

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, batch-processing

I have a file named "01 - Welcome To The Jungle.mp3", and I want to do `eyeD3 -t "Welcome To the Jungle" 01 - Welcome To The Jungle.mp3` to modify the tag of the all the files in the folder. I've extracted from the file with awk: "Welcome To The Jungle" doing:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in *.mp3
do
eyeD3 -t $(echo ${i} | awk -F' - ' '{print $2}' | awk -F'.' '{print $1}') ${i}
done
```

It doesn't work. Neither the whole "$(echo S{i}....)" nor the "${i}" seem to work for replacing the names of the respective files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to double-quote variables that may contain spaces, as @heemayl already pointed out.

Also, in this example, instead of using `awk`,
it would be better to use native Bash pattern substitution to extract the title, for example:

```
for file in *.mp3; do
    title=${file%.mp3}
    title=${title#?????}
    eyeD3 -t "$title" "$file"
done
```

That is:

- Remove `.mp3` at the end
- Remove the first 5 characters (the count prefix `NN -`)

Comment: Thank you so much @janos! I didn't even know you could do that! And it looks so much more intuitive than the awk command!

Comment: No, Thank you. I think I understand it now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to prevent word splitting on `IFS` (default: space, tab, newline) by shell, as your input filename contains space(s). The typical workaround is to use double quotes around the variable expansion.

Do:

```
for i in *.mp3; do eyeD3 -t "$(echo "$i")" | ...; done
```

You can leverage here string, `<<<`, to avoid the `echo`-ing:

```
for i in *.mp3; do eyeD3 -t <<<"$i" | ...; done
```